# VSCode - what is the meaning of a question mark in the code format provided by VScode

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]

In the picture, the description of `done()`, VSCode informs the type of parameters with a colon `error: any` or sometimes with question mark and colon `user?: any`.

What is the difference between them?

I mean, what's the difference between using only colon and using colon with question mark when VSCode presenting types?

Comment: Check the documentation for the `done()` function and you should find the explanation

Answer (score 2):

The question mark signifies an optional parameter. When calling `done`, `error` is a mandatory parameter, that you must always provide. `user` is optional, so you don't need to provide it when calling.

Here is an example for defining optional parameter.

[image: Defining optional parameter]